# MVC Html.Hidden - @ does make a difference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have the following piece of code :

```
@if (Model.A == Model.B)
{
    Html.Hidden("a1", Model.A1);
}
else
{
    Html.Hidden("a2", Model.A2);
}
```

With the above piece of code the hidden fields are not created and I don't get any errors.

After 30 minutes I realized that if I put the @ behind Html.Hidden it works :

```
@if (Model.A == Model.B)
{
    @Html.Hidden("a1", Model.A1);
}
else
{
    @Html.Hidden("a2", Model.A2);
}
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: The "@" indicates that the following text is Razor code so it won't be parsed as HTML.   http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/razor_syntax.asp

Comment: Are you asking why there was no error, or why you need `@`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Html` is a form property that maps to an instance of `HtmlHelper`.  `HtmlHelper.Hidden` *returns* a `MvcHtmlString`

```
Html.Hidden("a1", Model.A1);
```

*does nothing* as the returned value is not captured.  **You don't get any errors because it's perfectly valid C# code** (capturing the return is optional).  Most static analysis tools, however, will warn you about this since it's most likely a bug (as you have discovered).

On the other hand,

```
@Html.Hidden("a1", Model.A1);
```

is analagous to

```
Response.Write(Html.Hidden("a1", Model.A1));
```

which writes the return value to the HTML response.

Comment: I know it's nitpicky, but the semi-colon at the end of your middle code block shouldn't be there to be truly analogous. +1 anyway.

Comment: @itsme86 That's why I said _analagous_ and not _exactly equal to_. :)